# Maven repository and mirror with the same ID

Tags: maven

In a project I wanted to use the same ID for a repository and mirror to avoid duplicating my credentials:

**pom.xml**

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>company-artifactory</id>
      <url>https://company-artifactory/project-specific-maven-repository</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

**settings.xml**

```xml
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>company-artifactory</id>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
      <mirror>
      <id>company-artifactory</id>
      <url>https://company-artifactory/proxy-of-maven-central</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

I expected the project to use the repository defined in `pom.xml` and the mirror for `central` (which is defined in the super POM). Both should use the same credentials (`company-artifactory`). This does not work. It seems that the repository overrides the mirror:

```
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.mycompany.app:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [company-artifactory (https://company-artifactory/project-specific-maven-repository, default, releases+snapshots)]
```

If I change the name of the `mirror` to `central-mirror`, I get:

```
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.mycompany.app:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [company-artifactory (https://company-artifactory/project-specific-maven-repository, default, releases+snapshots), central-mirror (https://company-artifactory/proxy-of-maven-central, default, releases)]
```

For me, the Maven documentation is not a 100% clear whether

> id, name: The unique identifier and user-friendly name of this mirror.

refers to a unique identifier among mirrors or a unique identifier "globally".
Source: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#mirrors

If Maven does not support this, is there any other way to avoid duplicating the credentials?

Comment: Using the same credentials for different things? Good idea? And no the id has to be unique...

Comment: They are not different things. It is one Artifatory instance for which I have one (!) set of credentials. And even if I would want to do that. Who are you to judge?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that using environment variables in the `settings.xml` is supported, therefore the following is a good solution:

**settings.xml**

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>company-artifactory</id>
      <username>${env.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>company-mirror</id>
      <username>${env.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```